# The trip of a lifetime... but to where?

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, cipher

Your best friend Alex is great, but she's a *bit* too into puzzles for your taste.

Today, she sent you a package. It included a letter informing you that she’s planned the adventure of a lifetime for the two of you for next year… if you can figure out **where the adventure will be**, and the **combination of the safe** in which she locked the plane tickets (well, she probably just printed out the email confirmation, but you get the idea). It’s locked with a four letter code. Yeah, she mailed a small safe for the sake of a puzzle. That's Alex for you.

All you have to go on is this note she included with the letter:

```
My dear friend and fellow adventurer! 
I’m so excited to travel with you. 
The lines may be long at the airport, 
but they’ll be worth it once we get to our destination. 
Unfortunately (please don’t be cross!), I locked up the tickets 
and you’ll have to solve a puzzle before we go. 
It shouldn’t be too difficult; 
just start at the beginning.
```

On the back of the note is the following block of text. Looks like gibberish to you, but you're pretty sure it's not. It *is* Alex, after all, and this is a lot of nonsense to painstakingly write out in all capitals like this.

```
OWGUCNCNNFQYRXFGPTUGJBN
MWJEIVFCAJWHPIOFTSWKQZD
DTSTBWEKOGAFQYRXYUMSCGV
RNURZXCILFXJJKCFQXBUTKO
JRTPHTSHRXWGJFQYVPOUQLH
DLOWOPRUYIOWXAWQFQLZRNG
KHFWXUMQQYRXFXJFQYRBXNX
NKPVVXOUKIYIOWXAWHYQPZU
QXKLBOAMXAQYROFGJFQXYLL
MQMESJETBDJFYIXNYWAWLIG
RNXOBEFPNXSQQPRBTPWXXSF
GSYWRXPXHJUSFQYYKLSEPED
NHMLALXTNAZCEWGOYXBUUVX
SJFTPWJCMXPNRNSYMAKOSXT
DDVMNNUZCTXPWCXPDCGFRMZ
LHDFHXOALESJDTOWOCCDDFN
PWZMJEWRKJEHEFRYIWWMZKI
LYFEAXOOTUJEHJRWBWMBSFF
JUSWKLZJKUPXPPXKTKVOHED
RXCAOECEDRYUODSYDQTETLP
```

And finally, right below that, scrawled in a different color:

<strike>FCJLIRJVYHNXQASSRKHVNCEDYPMSEBZEWWDBZFLVBZIXIOOIGWHVTCQEYGHPFYTNTZXXVHTUFGXFQYORROXXCARWTSIIFQXMHWGZGWENGEZHSVWPFCYELEZXLGZIAMTLAHIYGDLAGZCMSXDFMWRDVYKIIFWWTZPL</strike>

PLEASE NOTE: the original had a copy-paste error with one letter missing, and the updated scrawl is here:

> **FCJLIRJVYHNXQASSRKHVNCEDYPMSEBZEWWDBZFLVBZIXIOOIGWHVTCQEYGHPFYTNTZXXVHTUFGXFQYORROXXCARWTSIIFQXMHWGZGWENGEZHSVWPFCYELEZFXLGZIAMTLAHIYGDLAGZCMSXDFMWRDVYKIIFWWTZPL**

So, where the heck is Alex taking you, and how will you open the safe to get the tickets?

Comment: Pretty certain it’s some sort of polyalphabetic cipher (likely vigenere?) based on the IC value, and the IC for key length suggests key length is most likely a multiple of 4 (and most likely 8). No idea for the key however, but perhaps there’s a hint somewhere in the first piece of text... (just throwing this out there as this is as far as I’ve got)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil You're on the right track!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**You are going to**:

> **Spitsbergen**!

**And the Safe combo is**:

> **SSNR**

---

I had no idea where to start with this, so did some cryptanalysis. The [Index of Coincidence](https://www.dcode.fr/index-coincidence) was $0.04082$ suggesting a polyalphabetic cipher (therefore likely vigenere), and running probable key lengths suggested that the most likely key length would be 8. Now things started to fall into place!

The first important piece of information is the line:

> 'just start at the beginning'

So...

> Taking the first letters of the first sentences gives us the 8 letter key '**MITBUAIJ**' and using this as a key on the ciphertext gives:
>
> ```
> CONTINUEBXXXXXXXDLBFPBF
> DKBLHBFURXOOOOOXKGORPFD
> VKGLIVKKGXOXXXXXQLAKJFB
> RFLFREBOLXOXBRBLQPSILRN
> PRLGVLZGXXOXXXXXBPGLEDO
> CROOFDJBXOOOOOOXEWLRIBY
> RGLWPLAIXXXXXOXXXXXBPEL
> FROBVPFICPXOOOOOOOXWPRL
> EPRKHOSDLSXXXOXXXXXWELD
> DEELRPELSRBMXOXFPKSDKOG
> JELGIDLPFOGIXOXBLGKPERL
> GKPKJEODHBLGXXXEKDJSHLC
> THECODESTARTSONNEXTLINE
> RPFLGKBJLDPFIBKFLGKGJLL
> KCBMFEIRJSDPOTLHKBMFJDN
> DOCLHPFODLRPDLFKGJBJDXE
> DOGLPEOIYBLGKFJPWODLFKA
> CMXLZDOGKIBLGPROSKEIRLF
> BLGORKFJCLDPWODKLBJGODJ
> RPTOGLBKDJPIGKREDIKSLSO
> ```

This says

> '**Continue**' then some other cipher text. Then about halfway through it says '**The code starts on next line**' followed by more cipher text.

From here:

> There are Xs and Os in the top half of the decoded text. These form a crossword grid: (thanks @Stiv for the image!)
>
>  [image]

And [@Leppyr64 found that](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/99946/18250) using the code in the bottom half as a key on the last string of ciphertext in the question gives:

> ONEACHIMNEYSIZINGEXPERTTWOANATIVETONGUELANDOFBLUELAGOONTHREEAONESQUAREFOURTRIANGLESONEDTINYIDEABITSTWODCAPITALSHORTDAYLONGXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXINTERSECTIONSARECOMBOXX
>
> These are crosswords clues followed by '**INTERSECTIONS ARE COMBO**'
>
> The crossword:
>
>  [image]
>
> (1D is incorrect)
>
> 1A: Santa is an expert at fitting down chimneys
> 2A: The blue lagoon is in Iceland, and 'Iceland' in Icelandic is 'Island'
> 3A: A pyramid can be formed with a square and four triangles
>
> 1D: ?
> 2D: Norway but I'm not 100% sure why

The crossword clues hint towards the location: (which @MrSethward somehow managed to find a long time before the crossword was completed :P)

> **[Spitsbergen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spitsbergen)** is an island in Norway, with a town called 'Pyramiden' (the pyramid).

And then using the information we have to find the combo

> 'INTERSECTIONS ARE COMBO' and the 4 intersections in the crossword grid are **SSNR**.

Very nice puzzle! :)

Comment: Great job with the first part. You probably don't need my confirmation that you got the first bit, since you got something that's not random characters back. :)

Comment: I'd forget the notion of binary for the two symbols you mention - check out the very clear [pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0mZm.png) they make in the top half of the stage-2 ciphertext. It looks to me like you could be dealing with something more like rot13(n jbeqfrnepu, n fgerrgznc, na vafgehpgvba xrlvat n genafsbezngvba... fbzrguvat zber culfvpny naljnl, engure guna fbzrguvat rapbqrq cre fr...)

Comment: @Stiv yeah I noticed that right as I left last night :P that’s a super helpful visual though thank you!!! And the fact it says that the code starts on the next line makes me think that the bit before it isn’t code at all, but I’m not sure what it could be

Comment: @Stiv, I tried to write the letters in the original cypher, that gave "O" according to this map, and there are a lot of repeated encrypted "words" there.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil, when I first saw your attempt and the somewhat decoded cypher, I thought to myself "maybe the upper half is the location, and the lower half gives the code."
See how the problem is worded, the "code" is only for unlocking the tickets.
As for the second cypher, it might be a congratulatory note from Alex (well, from the OP really)! What do you think?

Comment: 3a could equally be rot13(CLENZVQ - vzntvar gur 2-qvzrafvbany arg...). As for 1a, how about some kind of acronym like [rot13(OSPZN)](http://www.bfcma.co.uk/)? I'm wondering whether what you end up with once all 5 are solved slots back into the original position, for further decryption (or if the crossover points are important...).

Comment: Hey @Beastly, nice work on the bottom half. Some ideas: rot13(V guvax BAR FDHNER SBHE GEVNATYRF --> CLENZVQ. Sbe gur ANGVIR GBATHR OYHR YNTBBA, avpr, V jnf guvaxvat vg pbhyq nyfb or VFYNAQ, fvapr gung vf gur bssvpvny anzr bs Vprynaq naq zber trareny. Jvgu gung, V gubhtug A_E___ *pbhyq* or Abejnl (nygubhtu V pna'g znxr urnqf be gnvyf bs gur pyhr), juvpu jbhyq cbvag gbjneqf Fcvgforetra, na vfynaq va Abejnl jvgu na nonaqbarq zvavat snpvyvgl pnyyrq gur clenzvq be Finyoneq, gur nepuvcryntb vg'f n cneg bs. (guvf ynfg ovg vf n fgergpu un, ohg V'z fghpx bgurejvfr))

Comment: Also, you should adjust rot13(3N hc gb vagrefrpg 2Q ng gur 3eq yrggre).

Comment: 1A might be rot13(Fnagn). If 2A alternative by @MrSethward is true than 1D might be rot13(Fvtaf)

Comment: @SilentAxe Or rot(FGHOF) for 1d...

Comment: I've updated the crossword so its blank (and correct) and listed all suggestions so far underneath. Thanks everyone for your ideas! This seems quite tricky

Comment: Rot13(Aneivx jbhyq svg npebff Vfynaq naq Clenzvq ohg V'z abg fher ubj vg eryngrf gb pyhrf bgure guna orvat pncvgny bs gur zhavpvcnyvgl ybpngrq jurer qnlf ner fubeg va jvagre)

Comment: Hey y'all - this is so embarrassing, but I just realized that in all of my copy pasting, despite painstaking review, I missed one letter in the scrawl at the bottom. I'm so sorry - but for the rest of it you're 100% on the right track, and the very end of this puzzle should make sense now too. The updated scrawl is in the question.

Comment: Also - this is my very first puzzle I've ever made, and seeing y'all work through it is an absolute delight.

Comment: One more note: one of you in the comments above literally has gotten the right answer to the first part of the question.

Comment: @kristinalustig no worries at all! This is very good first puzzle and ciphers like these are hard to pull off but youve done a good job! As to the location, I believe only 2 have been listed so I guess were almost there :P

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil That string isn't correct. rot13(Ubj jnf vg bevtvanyyl qrpelcgrq, naq jung qbrf gung gryy lbh sbe ubj vg arrqf gb or qrpelcgrq abj?)

Comment: Here you go pal, the new decrypted string
rot13(BARNPUVZARLFVMVATRKCREGGJBNANGVIRGBATHRYNAQBSOYHRYNTBBAGUERRNBARFDHNERSBHEGEVNATYRFBARQGVALVQRNOVGFGJBQPNCVGNYFUBEGQNLYBATKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKVAGREFRPGVBAFNERPBZOBKK)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil looks like all but one are correct, but i'd go ahead and update it because you have enough to share your answer.

Comment: YES! Great job, team. 1D is incorrect - the correct answer gives another hint to the location, but the location and code are right. Thank you for doing my puzzle! And FWIW I've been here on vacation and it was incredible.

Comment: @kristinalustig very nice puzzle!! Was a good difficulty level and had multiple layers, and was fun to solve. I have no idea for 1D or 2D but I'll leave them to see if someone else can solve/explain them. Only feedback I would have would be the letters around the crossword grid weren't used and hence were a little off-putting so perhaps you could have made them spell something, or just made them all Xs or something along those lines. Besides that, great puzzle!! Especially for a first one, thank you for posting it :)

Answer (score 6):

Partial Answer Continuing from Beastly Gerbil's Answer:

Decrypting

> FCJLIRJVYHNXQASSRKHVNCEDYPMSEBZEWWDBZFLVBZIXIOOIGWHVTCQEYGHPFYTNTZXXVHTUFGXFQYORROXXCARWTSIIFQXMHWGZGWENGEZHSVWPFCYELEZXLGZIAMTLAHIYGDLAGZCMSXDFMWRDVYKIIFWWTZPL
>
>  with this OTP key:
>
>  RPFLGKBJLDPFIBKFLGKGJLLKCBMFEIRJSDPOTLHKBMFJDNDOCLHPFODLRPDLFKGJBJDXEDOGLPEOIYBLGKFJPWODLFKACMXLZDOGKIBLGPROSKEIRLFBLGORKFJCLDPWODKLBJGODJRPTOGLBKDJPIGKREDIKSLSO

Gives:

> ONEA CHIMNEY SIZING EXPERT
>  TWOA NATIVE TONGUE LAND OF BLUE LAGOON
>  THREEA ONE SQUARE FOUR TRIANGLES
>  ONED TINY IDEA BITS
>  TWOD CAPITAL SHORT DAY LONG
>  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX INTERSECTIONS ARE COMBO XX

These seem to be:

> Clues for the crossword in BeastlyGerbil's image.  ONEA is one across, ONED is one down.

Strangely:

> The remaining text and the PAD are not the same length...

Comment: Ah I tried decrypting the other way round but didnt try that way :P Nice work!! I have no idea what that riddle means though

Comment: I commented this on the other answer too, bu to make sure you see it: I just realized that in all of my copy pasting, despite painstaking review, I missed one letter in the scrawl at the bottom. The updated is in the question.

Comment: @kristinalustig Thanks I figured something was up.